# Why assigning count of a query to a variable performed better than checking it directly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

Recently I had a performance tuning experience and I want to share it here and trying to understand why this improvement happened.

In one of my procs, I wanted to return a data set based on existence of some other records.

My query:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ...) > 0
    SELECT …
```

This query was taking around 5 seconds.

I made a change and assigned the output of `IF` statement to a variable then check it.

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0
SELECT @cnt = COUNT(1) FROM …

IF @cnt > 0
    SELECT …
```

This one takes less than 1 sec to run.

Also I tried `IF EXISTS` as well but got the same result before the improvements (5 sec).

I am very keen to know why the compiler behaves that much different and if there is any particular answer for that.

Thank you

Comment: Paul White gave a very good answer on dba.se: [IF EXISTS taking longer than embedded select statement](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126235/if-exists-taking-longer-than-embedded-select-statement) This question should be marked as a duplicate, but the answer is not on SO.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBaranov to point out that question. Was very helpful but I want to know why there is a difference between assigning it to a variable and calling it directly. My intent in here is not using `IF EXISTS`.

Comment: Most likely optimizer converts `IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ...) > 0` into `IF EXISTS ...`. I thought that was mentioned in the answer by Paul White, but now I don't see it there. I must have seen it somewhere else. Check the execution plan. If optimizer indeed converts `IF COUNT>0` into `IF EXISTS`, then introduction of a row goal with `EXISTS` would explain non-optimal execution plan that you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts here.

1) SQL Server optimizer converts

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ...) > 0
    SELECT …
```

into

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ...)
    SELECT …
```

I've seen that this was pointed out by Adam Machanic in his comment to the post by Andrew Kelly [Exists Vs. Count(*) - The battle never ends](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx):

> It's interesting to note that in SQL Server 2005 if there is a index
>   available to allow a seek, the COUNT(*) > 0 test will be optimized and
>   behave the same as EXISTS.

Adam provided there a demo.

---

2) Sometimes `EXISTS` is worse than `COUNT`:

[IF EXISTS taking longer than embedded select statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126235/if-exists-taking-longer-than-embedded-select-statement)

[Check existence with EXISTS outperform COUNT! … Not?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46359/check-existence-with-exists-outperform-count-not)

As Paul White [wrote](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126314/57105):

> Using `EXISTS` introduces a row goal, where the optimizer produces an
>   execution plan aimed at locating the first row quickly. In doing this,
>   it assumes that the data is uniformly distributed. For example, if
>   statistics show there are 100 expected matches in 100,000 rows, it
>   will assume it will have to read only 1,000 rows to find the first
>   match.
>
> This will result in longer than expected execution times if this
>   assumption turns out to be faulty. For example, if SQL Server chooses
>   an access method (e.g. unordered scan) that happens to locate the
>   first matching value very late on in the search, it could result in an
>   almost complete scan. On the other hand, if a matching row happens to
>   be found amongst the first few rows, performance will be very good.
>   This is the fundamental risk with row goals - inconsistent
>   performance.

---

If your data distribution is skewed or if you expect that in majority of cases the `COUNT` would be zero (i.e. you have to scan the whole table anyway to get the answer), then you should try to get the plan without a row goal (i.e. without `EXISTS`).

One obvious way as you found already is to save results of `COUNT` into a variable.

Comment: Thank you for all these useful info. I just leave it open for a while to get some more attention.